# MongoDB (Mongoose) `findByIdAndDelete` not deleting (testing with Postman)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got my Mongoose code in a separate `model.js` file, while Express code for handling http requests is in `app.js`. I'm just practising creating APIs and testing them on Postman, for an imaginary wiki article site. The api I'm struggling to get it to work is deleting one article. (Note: for the sake of brevity, I've only included the code in question, i.e. `app.delete('/articles/:id' ....` from `app.js`, and the static method it calls from `model.js` - `deleteOneArticleFromDB(articleID)`

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const model = require('./model');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.delete('/articles/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const articleID = req.params.id;
    console.log(`req.params.id: ${req.params.id}`);
    try {
        const response = await model.DBUtility.deleteOneArticleFromDB(articleID);
        res.status(200).json({message: response, app: 'wiki-api'});
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err, app: 'wiki-api'});
    }
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

`model.js`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String
});

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);

class DBUtility {

    static deleteOneArticleFromDB(articleID) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Article.findByIdAndDelete(articleID, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(`Deleted article ${articleID} successfully`);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

exports.DBUtility = DBUtility;
```

I have 5 articles (5 documents) in my Database:

```js
{
    "_id" : "5c139771d79ac8eac11e754a",
    "title" : "API",
    "content" : "API stands for Application Programming Interface. It is a set of subroutine definitions, communication protocols, and tools for building software. In general terms, it is a set of clearly defined methods of communication among various components. A good API makes it easier to develop a computer program by providing all the building blocks, which are then put together by the programmer."
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5c1398aad79ac8eac11e7561",
    "title" : "Bootstrap",
    "content" : "This is a framework developed by Twitter that contains pre-made front-end templates for web design"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "5c1398ecd79ac8eac11e7567",
    "title" : "DOM",
    "content" : "The Document Object Model is like an API for interacting with our HTML"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "5ea2c188fa57aa1b6453eda5",
    "title" : "Node JS",
    "content" : "Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform, JavaScript runtime environment that executes JavaScript code outside of a web browser. Node.js lets developers use JavaScript to write command line tools and for server-side scripting—running scripts server-side to produce dynamic web page content before the page is sent to the user's web browser. Consequently, Node.js represents a \"JavaScript everywhere\" paradigm,[6] unifying web-application development around a single programming language, rather than different languages for server- and client-side scripts.",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "5ea2d5304e19b11e0013a86a",
    "title" : "EJS",
    "content" : "EJS is a simple templating language that lets you generate HTML markup with plain JavaScript. No religiousness about how to organize things. No reinvention of iteration and control-flow. It's just plain JavaScript",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I'm trying to delete the last article (document) with title `EJS`. So in Postman I run the http request as follows:

[image]

As you can see, I get a success response. However, when I check my database, the document is still there (I have clicked refresh several times and also tested it with a GET request to return all articles, which showed the article is still there):
[image]

Here's the terminal output:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started on port 3000
req.params.id: 5ea2d5304e19b11e0013a86a
```

I've been on this for two days. I've checked all previous SO posts with similar titles to mine, but I couldn't see one that applies to my issue. I don't understand where I'm going wrong!! Any help would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As per the solution below by Mohammed Yousry, I realised that I added the `_id` field manually using strings, as I was following along to a tutorial. Hence not allowing MongoDB to create the `_id` field instead, as an `ObjectId`. Therefore, my `_id` field was of type String rather than ObjectId. So to resolve this, I deleted all documents from the database and re-added them, using POSTMAN with the POST method I created - for creating/adding a new article document to the database, providing only the `title` and `content` fields in the request body. Hence allowing MongoDB to create the `_id` field instead, for each article document. Now in the database the `_id` field is of type `ObjectId`. This still hasn't resolved my issue fully, but it's one step further. Still working on reaching a solution. Please refer to the discussions below in the solution section.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- may be your `mongoose` version does not support `findByIdAndDelete`

try `findByIdAndRemove` instead

2- you can pass the id to that method as a string or as an objectId

make sure you are passing the right id without any spaces

```
const articleID = req.params.id.toString().trim(); // trim will remove any spaces before or after the id
```

---

### Update

according to this image

[image]

it seems you have inserted your data manually, and these data contained the `_id` as a string, as the type of the `_id` is a string here as you can see in this image

I suggest you to let `MongoDB` to set the `_id` itself

If you could change the `_id` type to be `ObjectId`

or If you can't change the type of `_id`, you can take a backup of your articles, then remove all those articles manually and add them again without the _id, let mongoDB set that _id, and try your code again

hope this may solve the issue

---

---

### Update 2

After checking the codes in github, I know the reason why you got this strange behavior

1- you have a route `app.route('/articles/:articleTitle')` defined before the route `app.delete('/articles/:id'`

so when you are trying to delete some article by passing the id, nodeJS an express will pass it to the first matching route, as it does not know the `params` you send, it's searching for the base `url` in the `route`, so it deals with the first route which matching the `url` : `'/articles/something'`, take that something as the article title

then call the `deleteOneArticleByTitleFromDB` method

MongoDB is then searching for some article with title = the id you passed, it found nothing, then, it doesn't remove any article

2- I suggest you not to define some routes with the same base url

so you can define the delete by Id route like the following

```
app.delete('/arti/cles/:id', async (req, res) => // note the slash inside articles word
```

or anything you want except the current one

by this you avoid this contradiction between the routes

Comment: Apologies for my late reply, I was trying your solution as well as others. Thank you for your suggestion. I'm on Mongoose version 5.9.10, which documentation includes this api. I've tried all your suggestions, unfortunately nothing is working. I've tried a combination of your solution and the first solution in this post from `Reqven`. I've tried many different combinations nothing is working. I've done another DELETE api based on the `title` field using `deleteOne`, and that worked straight away. I used `deleteOne` but using the `_id` query, and guess what, it didn't work either.

Comment: Clearly there's something about the ID that is not working. I've been on this issue for 4 days now. It's been a very frustrating experience, and frankly I've ran out of all ideas now.

Comment: I've  tried `const articleID = req.params.id.toString().trim();` then passed this to the api `try {
        const response = await model.DBUtility.deleteOneArticleByIdFromDB(articleID);
        res.json({message: response, app: 'wiki-api'});
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err, app: 'wiki-api'});
    }`

Comment: I've tried `const articleID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);`. Didn't work. Then I've tried a combination of `const articleID = req.params.id.toString().trim();
    const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(articleID);`. Didn't work.

Comment: I keep getting the success message returned in postman, i.e. the success JSON response. But nothing is being deleted from the Database.

Comment: could you `console.log(articleID)` before that query `Article.findByIdAndDelete(articleID, (err) => {` in `model.js` file

Comment: also, I've updated my answer, could you check it again?, hope it helps

Comment: Great. Well spotted :)  Indeed I have added the _id field manually as I was following along to a tutorial. However, the tutorial didn't show how to create a DELETE api for deleting by ID. Only by the article `title` field. This is where I decided to take it a step further and add one extra DELETE api, to delete by the `_id` field. So as you suggested, what I have done is deleted all documents from the database, and this time I used the POST request instead to add each article at a time to the DB, by providing only the `title` and `content` fields this time, in the body of the POST request.

Comment: Thus allowing MongoDB to create the `_id` field instead for each article. Now the database shows the `_id` field of type ObjectId. I have provided an update in my original post to show a screenshot of this.

Comment: Unfortunately this still hasn't resolved the issue. Again I tried a different combination of your solution and the one by `Reqven`, to no avail. The weird is, I placed `console.log(articleID)` inside my HTTP method, and nothing is getting outputted in the Terminal. However, the HTTP request is still returning success message JSON of the `_id` value. How is it doing that, but not outputting the console log I placed inside the http handler, I'm really confused!!

Comment: Anyway, I thought to make this easier, I'm sharing the link to my Github repo, so that you can clone it. I'm sure this will be a lot easier for you. Let me know if you face any issues. Thanks. Github repo: https://github.com/hazzaldo/build-my-own-restful-apis-wiki-api.git

Comment: after checking the codes in github, I've updated my answer again, could you check it?

Comment: Brilliant job. Thank you very much for your persistance to solve this issue. Despite the time spent, I'm so glad to go through this issue and realise this crucial rule that I over-looked, by assuming that the Route Params are treated as if they're different routes, when in fact the route is processed at its base and path, and the route params are treated as simply passing parameters (but not treated as different routes). I tested it with route `/articles/article/:id` i.e. having a different route and it works now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB, the `_id` property is of type `ObjectId`.
I had the same problem and fixed it by passing over an `ObjectId` instead.

Have you tried the following ?

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const articleId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Reqven. I modified my code like so (sorry I wish SO would allow for comment replies to be have a nice format for code): `static deleteOneArticleFromDB(articleID) {
        const objectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(articleID);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Article.findByIdAndDelete(objectId, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(`Deleted article ${objectId} successfully`);
                }
            });
        });
    }`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Same response with the JSON showing success of deleted document with its ID, but the document is still in the DB. I just checked the DB and did a GET request of all articles which included the one that is supposed to be deleted.

Comment: I tried to modify the code on the `app.js` side instead, like so: `app.delete('/articles/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const articleID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
    try {
        const response = await model.DBUtility.deleteOneArticleFromDB(articleID);
        res.status(200).json({message: response, app: 'wiki-api'}); .... `  . But still doesn't work. Same success response, but the document doesn't delete from the DB

Comment: I'll keep working on it, and post the answer if I get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

@Hazzaldo I was facing the same problem. But apparently, I didn't write await before findByIdAndDelete(). After writing await before it fixed it for me.
I saw your code, as you are wrapping the findByIdAndDelete inside a promise which in itself is a promise, I would recommend you to try to await the findByIdAndDelete first and then return the promise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used a completely different logic on the backend.

```
export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    // Confirm data
    if (!id) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Note ID found' })
    }
    // Confirm note exists 
    const post = await PostMessage.findById(id).exec()
    if (!post) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Note not found' })
    }
    const result = await post.deleteOne()
    const reply = `Post '${result.title}' with ID ${result._id} deleted`
    res.json(reply)
}
```