# cannot DELETE post (express mongoose postman)

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I'm trying to do simple REST operations with Postman request on  `http://localhost:5000/posts/60c9b65463cdb804e4238257` but with DELETE I'm getting this error:

`404 not found Cannot DELETE /posts/60c8e5a860b84f0013a1d9d7`

I will be glad for any tips.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL9P8.jpg

```js
// index.js

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/posts", postRoutes);
```

```js
//routes.js

const routes = express.Router();

routes.get("/", getPosts);
routes.post("/", createPost);
routes.patch("/:id", updatePost);
router.delete("/:id", deletePost);
export default routes;
```

```js
// controller.js

export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
    return res.status(404).send(`No post with id: ${id}`);

  try {
    await Bootcamp.findByIdAndDelete(id);

    res.json({ message: "Post deleted successfully.",success:true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: flase, message: error.message });
  }
};

export default router;
```

Comment: And the document with _id 60c8e5a860b84f0013a1d9d7 exists in the bootcamps collection?

Comment: yes it does I tried with other docs and had same error just diff id tho

Comment: Weird, maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418553/mongodb-mongoose-findbyidanddelete-not-deleting-testing-with-postman

Comment: I was looking on that but i do not understand why PATCH is without problems and similar DELETE does this....

Comment: The problem is not with mongoose or any database - it's with the router and how you send the request. Please show us the Postman request code, or we cannot help you :)

Comment: I have added screenshot from postman

Comment: mongodb by default add ```_id``` as ```id``` so you need to find by the key not ```id```. Your query should be like ```await Bootcamp.findOneAndDelete({_id: id});```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a "s" in your `delete` router line.

```
const routes = express.Router();

routes.get("/", getPosts);
routes.post("/", createPost);
routes.patch("/:id", updatePost);
router.delete("/:id", deletePost); // maybe it should be "routes"
export default routes;
```

`-> routes.delete("/:id", deletePost);`